# Calling .backward() on two different lossess triggers "Expected all tensors on the same device" RuntimeError?

Tags: python, pytorch, device, loss-function

I am developing a Python code using the Pytorch library to jointly train a generative model and a classification model, which grad I would use to generate conditioned samples.

I compute the classification model loss (*cls_loss*) and the generative model loss (*score_loss*) and then sum them, obtaining a *total_loss*. When I call *total_loss.backward()*, I get the following error: "**RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!**".

I already asserted that both losses, models and inputs are on the same device, cuda in this case. I also tried calling *.backward()* separately on the two losses, and I noticed that the error is triggered on the second *.backward()* calling, no matter if it is related to the *cls_loss *or the *score_loss *(I tried both ways, calling *cls_loss.backward()* and then *score_loss.backward()* and then the other way round).

I also want to specify that I am using two **different **losses and two **different **optimizers for training the two models. In addition, I already asserted that both losses are **not** NaN and they have the same size.

Does anyone have any idea about what the problem could be? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some code to try to reproduce this error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.